# One Firebase authentification for multiple non-permanent users - is it possible?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In a classroom, I'll provide to 100 users, 100 android devices, where they'll have to open an UNITY app.
Inside the app, I don't want the users to bother to enter any login, any email, any password.
So I guess they would need to be connected "automatically" to the same firebase account.
Then, they'll need to select one of the avatars available in firestore, with which they'll play and the app will save their avatar progress in firestore.
Is it possible to have so much players and devices using the same firebase account at the same time for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably first look at [signing in each device anonymously](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#anonymous-sign-in). That way each device/app instance has a unique, persistent identifier, without having the user enter any credentials.

You can then also use the UID in your database to have indicate the avatar that each user/device claims, and in the security rules of that database, to ensure users can only access data they're authorized for, and for example that each avatar can only be claimed by one user.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'll try this! Thank you!